# run octave in terminal meet out_of_range issue

Tags: c++, octave, data-science

I just ran "octave" in terminal in OSX 10.12.6 but it does not work anymore. 
Here is the error message:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: basic_string
panic: Abort trap: 6 -- stopping myself...
attempting to save variables to 'octave-workspace'...
save to 'octave-workspace' complete
Abort trap: 6
```

I tried to remove and reinstall from brew but it still does not work. My XCode is 9.2 and I installed some GNU Linux tools to replace my Mac's original ones. Is there any clue how I can resolve this problem?

Comment: try `brew install --build-from-source ...`

Comment: @Andy I uninstall forcely and install like you mentioned but still not work.